# Could not connect to localhost on port 3080 GNS3

Tags: python, networking, virtual-machine, gns3

I'm new to GNS3. When I installed it, I encountered an issue where I couldn't access the 3080 port. Despite turning off my firewall, the problem persists. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this bug?

I have tried the command "netstat -ano | findstr :3080" to check if the port is being used by another process, but it give me any response. This indicates that there is no process currently using the port.
version:2.2.40.1
CPU:AMD RYZEN 5 5600U

Comment: No response does not 'indicate that there is no process currently using the port'. It indicates a network connectivity problem. If you had connectivity and there was no listener you would get 'connection refused'.

Answer (score 0):

**Try accessing the port manually:** While GNS3 is running and attempting to connect to http://127.0.0.1:3080, open your web browser and manually enter this address. This may help establish the connection

**Check for port conflicts:** Although the netstat command did not show any processes using port 3080, there could still be a port conflict. Try changing the GNS3 server port to a different value, such as 3081, in the GNS3 settings and see if that resolves the issue